# React.js Router paramaters as attribute value

Tags: reactjs

I am learning Route parameters. The route is /secret/:image_name. The value I am writing to :image_name is night, which is also the name of image that is being imported. But the image is not displaying. Dow do I fix this?

```
import './secret.scss';
import React from "react";
import night from './images/night.png';
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function Secret() {
  let { image_name } = useParams();
  return (
    <>
      <div id="image-div"><img id="secret-image" src={image_name} /></div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Secret;
```

P.S. - Disregard any typo errors, the code compiles fine.

Comment: "night" isn't a valid source URL. Have you tried forming a fully qualified URL? In other words, the path up to, and including the "night" file name, and extension.

Comment: So your question is how to reference the imported `night` var as the `src` property of the `<img />`, correct?

Comment: Yes @BenM I am getting the name of image from parameter value.

Comment: night is valid source, the image is stored in night variable

Comment: What you actually put into the src is the string 'night' not the imported image night. So, it did not work. If you want to get the image locally based on the URL, You can build a  mapper instead. For example : mapper = {'night' : night}. so put src=mapper[image_name]